# calling an activity method from custom onClickListener class

Tags: java, android, class, scope

i trying to call a method that stays in my MainActivity class from custom `onClickListener` object. And there is something wrong with variable scope.

so in my MainActivity i have:

```
Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);
View.OnClickListener myListener = new MyListener(GameBoard, width);
resetButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

this is what my myListener class look like:

```
public class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private static MainActivity mainActivity;
    public MyListener(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mainActivity.myMethod();
    }
}
```

and method also in MainActivity that uses some MainActivity instance variables:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    InstanceVariable++;  // for example
}
```

Then when calling that myMethod on mainActivity object that i passing to myListener constructor by clicking resetButton i getting an error something about MainActivity `InstanceVariable` scope. I`m very beginner to android programming, so i cant fully understand where its coming from.

And this error disappears when i pass this `InstanceVariable` to `constructor` of `myListener object`. I think there should be an easier way to do that.

Comment: A static context like that is going to cause a huge memory leak

Comment: Why not, in your listner class, witch I suppose is a inner class of your MainActivity, call the method like this  : MainActivity.this.myMethod();

Comment: @GabeSechan Would you please explain that. I just confused about what is context exactly.

Comment: Context is an activity or a service.  If you keep a static reference to one around, the garbage collector won't be able to free it.  Which means it won't be able to free anything it references.  Which pretty much means no variable in your activity will ever be freed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
public void myMethod() {
    mainActivity.instanceVariable++;  // for example
}
```

instancevariable is not visible in your MyListener class, you have to point that it ts in the mainActivity  object.

If your instanceVariable is private, create getter function in mainActivity:

```
public void getInstanceVariable() {
   return this.instanceVariable
}
```

and use it this way:

```
public void myMethod() {
        mainActivity.setInstanceVariable(mainActivity.getInstanceVariable()+1);  // for example
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make **InstanceVariable** to

```
public static int InstanceVariable;
```

and use this

```
 @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MainActivity.InstanceVariable++;
    }
```

don't make methods for function that  has less than **8 lines**

Comment: yes, but i did that only for this post as short example

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Make your listener an inner class of your activity, then :

```
class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {

public MyListener() {

         }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MainActivity.this.myMethod();
}
```

}